# Handling AlertDialog buttons with data binding

Tags: android, mvvm, dialog, android-databinding

how can I handle AlertDialog's positive/negative/neutral buttons using MVVM and databinding in Android? I have list of items shown in RecyclerView and on click of an item, I want to show DialogFragment which allow to change or delete the item. If user click "OK", the item will be saved to database, if user click "Delete", the item will be deleted, and on "Cancel" the dialog will be dismissed. I don't know how to handle the listeners with databinding. Without it, I set the listners in onCreateDialog() like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setMessage(message);
builder.setTitle(title);
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, i) -> {});
builder.setNegativeButton(getContext().getString(R.string.text_cancel), (dialogInterface, i) -> dismissDialog());
builder.setNeutralButton(getContext().getString(R.string.text_delete), (dialogInterface, i) -> removeItem(item));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom adapter for your recyclerView, you could add to your view an onClickListener that shows the dialog and passes the position of the element clicked, so inside the onClickListener of the positiveButton you could just call the function to save it to your db:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    .
    .
    .

    viewHolder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this).create();
             alert.setTitle("....");
             alert.setMessage(".......");
             alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    saveToDb(List.get(position))

                 }
             });
            alert.show();
          
     });
}
```

Comment: Yes. I have custom adapter and everything works, but i'm wondering if it it a correct way when using MVVM. Shouldn't I somehow set button listeners in dialog's XML and do database stuf in ViewModel?

Comment: You shouldn't couple viewmodel with the adapter, a clean way is to declare the listener in your fragment/activity and pass it to the adapter, then just call setButton like this :                 alert.setButton("OK", okListener);    where okListener is an onClickListener implementation

Comment: No, I don't have VM in adapter. I have listener in Fragment (containig recyclerView) passed to Adapter and on touch of an item, the listener returns view and item position to Fragment, which opens DialogFragment. And now, I don't know how to handle buttons of this DialogFragment.